# What's best practice to check if an object is part of a ManyToMany relationship in Django

Tags: django, orm

from an instance of Site with a ManyToMany relationship to Kiosk, i'd like to check if a Kiosk object is part of the relationship.

I could do

```
self.apps.get(id=app_id).exists() and check if True
```

or

```
self.apps.get(id=app_id) and catch the ObjectDoesNotExist error
```

or

```
self.apps.filter(id=app_id) and check if True
```

- If I have to catch a possible ObjectDoesNotExist error, I may as well use the second one
- I can do the second but doesnt seem super clean
- can use the third one but using filter on a unique ID seems wrong to me

You can tell me to use whatever works and that'll be a valid answer ;-)

Comment: Why does using a filter on the ID seem wrong?

Comment: I would use the second option if you plan to work with the object and the third option if you only want to check if it's part of the relationship

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use

```
self.apps.filter(id=app_id).exists()
```

What's wrong with that?